# How do I define an excludecomment environment in a for loop?

Tags: pdftex, environments, loops, comments

I'm using the [forloop](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/forloop/) and comment packages to define environments `prob1` through `prob5` that exclude portions of my document. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{probnum}
\forloop{probnum}{1}{\value{probnum} < 6}{
    \excludecomment{prob\arabic{probnum}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{prob1}
hidden
\end{prob1}

shown
\end{document}
```

This throws an error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

when I compile it with Miktex pdfTex 2.9. It's not the loop that's causing the problem, because if I remove the code that actually uses the environment, it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual expansion problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{probnum}
\forloop{probnum}{1}{\value{probnum} < 6}{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\excludecomment{prob\arabic{probnum}}%
  }\x
}


\begin{document}
\begin{prob1}
hidden
\end{prob1}

shown
\end{document}
```

---

Alternative version with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\exclude}{mmm}
 {% #1 = prefix, #2 = start, #3 = end
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #2 } { 1 } { #3 }
   {
    \excludecomment{#1##1} % ##1 is the current step
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\exclude{prob}{1}{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{prob1}
hidden
\end{prob1}

shown
\end{document}
```